# Receiving 'Unhandled Promise Rejection' error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, geolocation, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm receiving this error while creating a live following line on my MapBox map.

I am having to use the same api somewhere else in this file. I'm guessing that is the issue.. Is there a way to solve this?

Error -

```
Error: There is already a source with this ID
    at i.addSource (mapbox-gl.js?e192:33)
    at r.addSource (mapbox-gl.js?e192:33)
    at VueComponent._callee5$ (Dashboard.vue?98fa:142)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:45)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:271)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:97)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?3b8d:5)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?3b8d:27)
```

Mounted call -

```
  mounted() {
    this.createMap();
      window.setInterval(() => {
        this.getLocation()
      }, 500)
  },
```

First API call -

```
async getLocation() {
  const res = await getLocations()
  this.center = [res.data[0].longitude,res.data[0].latitude];

  // Reverse Geocoding using MapBox API
  axios.get(`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${this.center}.json?access_token=${this.access_token}`)
      .then(async (response) => {
         this.loading = false;
         this.lat = response.data.query[1].toFixed(6);
         this.lng = response.data.query[0].toFixed(6);
         this.place_name = response.data.features[0].place_name;
         this.uncertainty_radius = res.data[0].uncertaintyRadiusInMeters;
         this.map.flyTo({center: [this.lng, this.lat], zoom: 16.5});
      });
  await this.mapMarker();
  await this.targetTrackingLine()
},
```

This is my following line function -

```
async targetTrackingLine() {
  if (this.lng !== "0.000000" && this.lng !== "") {
    const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${this.center}.json?access_token=${this.access_token}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    // save full coordinate list for later
    const coordinates = data.query;
    console.log(coordinates)
    // start by showing just the first coordinate
    data.query.coordinates = [coordinates[0]];
    // add it to the map
    this.map.addSource('trace', {type: 'geojson', data: data});
    this.map.addLayer({
      'id': 'trace',
      'type': 'line',
      'source': 'trace',
      'paint': {
        'line-color': '#000',
        'line-width': 4
      }
    });
    // on a regular basis, add more coordinates from the saved list and update the map
    let i = 0;
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (i < coordinates.length) {
        data.query.coordinates.push(coordinates[i]);
        this.map.getSource('trace').setData(data);
        i++;
      } else {
        window.clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, 10);
  }
}
```

Comment: did you want to remove the error message, or fix the error?

Comment: You should probably add a `catch` to handle the error first.

Comment: You would add the `catch` after your `then`. It should look something like `then(async(response)) => { // your logic }).catch(error => { // handle error });`.

Comment: I have no idea - the post does not supply the code that calls `targetTrackingLine`. The error message tells me that it (`targetTrackingLine`) is being called multiple times with no change to `this.map`. Perhaps the multiple calls are the bug you need to find.

Comment: Insert a line like `console.log( this.map.getontainer())` at the start of `targetTrackingLine` before everything else. You should be able to see the id of the HTML element containing the map on the console. Check log output confirms the method is only called once for the same map . (You may delete comments that are no longer relevent)

Comment: @traktor The getContainer method is indeed being called over and over. If I change it to only call the method once, how do I keep the method updating without multiplying the call to addSource?

Comment: Assuming `getContainer` output confirms that **targetTrackingLine** is being called multiple times for the same map, _and these calls are needed_, then generate a new source `id`  each time `targetTrackingLine` is called.

Comment: @traktor What would be the most economical way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code creates a new id to pass to `map.addSource` each time `targetTrackingLine` is called:

```
let targetTrackingCalls = 0;
async targetTrackingLine() {
   const sourceId = "trace" + ++targetTrackingCalls; // unique per call

   //... source lines
   this.map.addSource(sourceId, {type: 'geojson', data: data});

   //... in timer callback;

      this.map.getSource(sourceId).setData(data);

    //...
}
```

Using a unique id should prevent the error raised by [`addSource`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#addsource), always assuming `data` is a valid `geojason` object per the [MapBox specification](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/#geojson)